# pydantic: assign reference instead of copy when 'validate_assignment' is True

Tags: python, pydantic

Minimal working example:

```py
# okish:
from pydantic import BaseModel

class One(BaseModel):
    field1: list

class Two(One):
    field2: list
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.field1 = self.field2  # works, but no validation :(

# with assignment validation, but with reference copy "problem"
class OneV2(BaseModel):
    field1: list
    class Config:
        validate_assignment = True
       
class TwoV2(OneV2):
    field2: list
    class Config:
        validate_assignment = True
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.field1 = self.field2  # result in deep-copy, not reference assignment

# testing
_2 = Two(field1=[1], field2=[1, 2, 3])
_2.field1 is _2.field2  # True, as "expected"

_2_v2 = TwoV2(field1=[1, 2, 3], field2=[1, 2, 3, 4])
_2_v2.field1 is _2_v2.field2  # False, not expected
```

In short, I was expecting (and need) that a reference to `field2` is assigned to `field1` in `TwoV2` and am having difficulties to find the appropriate documentation. Any explanations or doc references would be highly appreciated.

python: 3.9
pydantic: '2.0'